# How to get rid of Sprint's notifications for ad-supported voicemail

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, voicemail, sprint

On my Galaxy S4 (Sprint), I regularly get a voicemail icon in my notification bar with the message:

> With this update, you will be able to enjoy premium Ad-supported features such as inline playback and auto forward to email.

I have no interest in "enjoying" these features, and I cannot figure out how to make it go away.

- "Allow automatic updating" is not not checked.
- I have no messages that haven't been listened to.
- I do not want to disable all notifications from the voicemail application, as I would  like to be notified when I have messages.
- Clearing the notification makes it go away for anywhere from 5 minutes to a day, but it always comes back.

[image: Sprint voicemail advertising garbage]

Is there any way that I can disable this specific message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accept the update, it doesn't charge you unless you subscribe to the premium package. Aside from that, you could decompile the apk and remove the push notification for updates.

Comment: Are there ads in my voicemail app then?

Comment: Where to find this APK? I searched all my filesystem from top to bottom but didn't find VoiceMail apk. Can you say where it's located?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove the ads from my Sprint voicemail without root.
On the Android device, go to **Voice mail > Menu > Settings > Uncheck Display Ads**.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: In what app is this?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following:

1. *Android Settings*
2. *Application Manager*
3. *All Apps* (drag page to the left)
4. search your app and tap on it
5. make shure, the box *show notifications* is unchecked
6. Problem solved?

Comment: As Brad wrote: *I do not want to disable all notifications from the voicemail application*, this does not solve his problem (as it does exactly that: disable *all* notifications), sorry.

Comment: hm, i see. this is what i did to ignore notification-spam of games etc... but to ignore specific notifications is not possible, i guess. Sorry this didnt work out.